# how to replace each individual occurrence of word with other word using awk or sed?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I wanted to replace each individual word present in 5 columns of a row with another word.

Here is my file (each column is separated by a tab, and when a column has multiple entries same as to each other they are separated by `,` (comma) like `"A_V,A_V,A_V,A_V"` ).

```
g1      A_chrococcum_B3__ACG10_RS21915  A_chrococcum_NCIMB8003__Achr_RS24720    "A_salinestris__GCU53_RS00995,A_salinestris__GCU53_RS13820,A_salinestris__GCU53_RS25085,A_salinestris__GCU53_RS00050,A_salinestris__GCU53_RS24715"     "A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS25530,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS00340,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS07835,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS09930,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS10910,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS11470,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS15230,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS21030,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS13765,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS06150,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS20865"   "A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS25600,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS00380,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS07870,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS09960,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS10940,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS11500,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS15260,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS06190,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS13795,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS20895"
```

The first column has the value with which I wanted to replace all other columns' values individually.

I'm looking for output like this (first col (string with I wanted to replace)). After first col COL-1 has only one occurrence therefore only one g1, COL-2  also has only one occurrence therefore only one g1, COL-3 has 5 occurrences, therefore, five g1, COL-4 has 11 occurrences therefore 11 g1 and so on.

```
g1      g1      g1      "g1,g1,g1,g1,g1"      "g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1"      "g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1"
```

I tried to do this for the first row and thought that I can loop it for the rest of the file. Also because I don't know how to do it for all the columns at once.

the command which I was trying:

```
 grep -w "g1" f1 |
 awk -F"\t" '{ gsub("A_.*,","g1",$4); print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}'
```

It gave me results like this:

```
g1      A_chrococcum_B3__ACG10_RS21915  A_chrococcum_NCIMB8003__Achr_RS24720    "g1A_salinestris__GCU53_RS24715"        "A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS25530,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS00340,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS07835,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS09930,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS10910,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS11470,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS15230,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS21030,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS13765,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS06150,A_vinelandii_CA__AVCA_RS20865"  "A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS25600,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS00380,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS07870,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS09960,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS10940,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS11500,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS15260,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS06190,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS13795,A_vinelandii_DJ__AVIN_RS20895"
```

How to do it? I have 677779 rows in my file.

Comment: Thanks for well written post, kudos for same. Your column 2 has only `A_` NOT `A_V`, could you please elaborate more on this one? Thank you.

Comment: A_ is common in all column whereas A_V is just an example it could be anything A_C, A_A

Comment: Yes, it is quite refreshing to find a well written, well formatted question that includes prior attempts at a solution. Well worth the nod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) gsub(/[^",]+/, $1, $i)} 1' file

g1 g1 g1 "g1,g1,g1,g1,g1" "g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1" "g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1,g1"
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine. But I wanted to include A_ in the replace field because in some rows I have * . something like this.
g5000    A_chrococcum_B3__ACG10_RS22345 
  A_chrococcum_NCIMB8003__Achr_RS22545     *       *       *

and in this case, I don't want to replace *.

Comment: I modified the command a little, its working but sill last * is getting replaced

                     awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=4; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i != "*"){ g
sub(/[^",]+/, $3, $i)}} 1'

Comment: Just use: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i != "*") gsub(/[^*",]+/, $1, $i)} 1' file`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#^(\S+).*#/^\1/s/[^"\\t,]+/\1/g#' file | sed -Ef - file
```

Create a sed script from the source file which replaces every field in every line by the first field of that line.

Invoke the sed script using the original source file as its input.

N.B. The sed script is passed into the second sed invocation by the use of the `-f -` command line option which evaluates a file of sed commands, that file is the standard input formed from the piping of the standard output from the first sed invocation.